# Select box items facing issue with title

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am having a select list with title to display tooltip.

Scenario:
I am having  two select list with different values.
One Select list with object1 and other select list with object2.
Based on the selected value in Object1 select list,the select list of Object2 values differ.

I have put title to each value in select list with Object2.Sometimes,I am not able to view the tool tip every time for Object2.

This happens whenever object2 select list has scroll bar.

In the source code,I am able to see the **title**,but on the UI I am not able to view the tool tip.

I am not bale to figure-out why its happening.
Code:

```
<label for="objsSelect">@Res.Strings.Objects</label>
<select id="objsSelect" class=" form-control" size="10" multiple></select>

function updateList(Type) {
        /// <summary>Updates the grants that the user can give</summary>

        try {
            var myobjs = m_myobjs[Type];

            // find matching object types
            var objDefs = $.grep(m_objDefinitions.getByObjectType(objectType), function (item) {
                /// <param name="item" type="server.objDefinition">Objectdefinition</param>

                var match = (m_isUser ||
                    myobjs.some(function (myObj) {
                        return item.ObjGuid === myObj.objGuid ||
                            item.GrantGuid === m_objDefinitions.getEffectiveobjGuid(myobj.ObjGuid);
                    }));

                return match;
            });

            // sort them by description
            objDefs.sort(function (a, b) {
                return a.Description.localeCompare(b.Description);
            });

            $(objDefs).each(function () {
                $objsSelect.append($("<option>").attr('value', this.ObjGuid).text(this.Description).attr('title', (this.TooltipDescription)));
            });

        }
        catch (error) {
            NMCApp.showNMCExceptionWindow(error);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you forgot to add this

```
data-toggle="tooltip"
```

To your created elements

Please check this [solution](https://jsfiddle.net/otw3mL13/)

You forgot to add Title

So it should look like this

```
<select id="grantsSelect" class="nmc-select form-control" size="10" data-toggle="tooltip" Title="Test" multiple>


  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>


</select>
```

Comment: I tried with the following and still not working,<select id="grantsSelect" class="nmc-select form-control" size="10" data-toggle="tooltip" multiple></select>

Comment: You still need to add the "title" Check updated solution.

Answer (score 0):

I figured the solution.I tried to reset the scroll bar position to top and it worked.

$objsSelect.scrollTop(0);